# HttpTestResult.getType returns UNKNOWN_TYPE for edittext

Tags: android, webview, android-edittext

i am disabling orientation change in my app. i need to enable it only when user tap on any edittext.there are some edittexts in my webview. i have added below code to do the same.

```
mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView)v).getHitTestResult();
        if(hr!=null){
            if(hr.getType()==HitTestResult.EDIT_TEXT_TYPE )
                ((Activity) context).setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
            else
                ((Activity) context).setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        return false;  
    }     
});
```

In android 4.0 device it is working fine. But in 2.2 OS hr.getType() returns unknown_type ie 0. how can i make it work in older versions too...